# Is there a way I can recover my unregistered account here?

Tags: discussion, email, user-accounts

3 days ago I correctly answered a question here which gained me 15 reps and I would like to recover that account that when I register I would still have that same amount of reps. Actually, I registered using the email account I provided as an unregistered account thru the email they sent me which led me to this account but I would like to redeem those reps I earned from when I wasn't a member?

Comment: If you can't, don't worry about it.  It will take only one mediocre answer to make up those points again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes. Use the contact us link at the bottom of the page and request an account merger.](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: It worked! Wow, that was simple! Thank you so much!